# SAPUI5 Create OData entity with dates - generates incorrect request payload that ends in CX_SXML_PARSE_ERROR

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

We are trying to create an entity that has date attributes via an odata service. Backend is an sap system. This entity has only 3 key attributes plus a bunch of other attributes. We have identified that dates in the keys are the root cause of the problem.

Keys:

- Pernr type string,
- begda type datetime
- endda type datetime.

The code below, (which does not work), has been severely simplified when trying to troubleshoot the issue. At the moment, it reads an entity from an entity set and immediately tries to create one with exactly the same data.

Code:

```
var oODataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_PERSONAL_DATA_SRV/");

//Test entity to be saved
var entity = null;

//Handler for read error
var handleReadE = function (oEvent){ 
    alert("error");
};

//Handler for read success
var handleRead = function (oEvent){
    //Get the data read from backend
    entity = oEvent.results[0];

    //Try to create a new entity with same data
    oODataModel.create('/PersDataSet', entity, null, function(){
        alert("Create successful");
    },function(oError){
        alert("Create failed", oError);
    });
};

oODataModel.read("/PersDataSet", null, [], true, handleRead, handleReadE);
```

In the gateway error log, an xml parsing error appears. In this log, we can see the request data and it can be seen that the dates are transported with String types. These dates are defined in the service as DateTimes so the request is rejected. 
Example:

```
<m:properties>
<d:Pernr m:type="Edm.String">00000001</d:Pernr>
    <d:Endda m:type="Edm.String">9999-12-31T00:00:00</d:Endda>
    <d:Begda m:type="Edm.String">1979-05-23T00:00:00</d:Begda>
```

When the entity is read, the backend does not send any type information. It sends like the following example:

```
<m:properties>
   <d:Pernr>72010459</d:Pernr>
   <d:Endda>9999-12-31T00:00:00</d:Endda>
   <d:Begda>1876-07-21T00:00:00</d:Begda>
```

And, indeed, if we try to save the same info without the type=".." it works. So the problem are the incorrect types ODataModel.create adds to the xml.

My question is:
Can I tell ODataModel.create to not add this type info? It is not doing a good job inferring the types.

Can anyone share an example reading and writing dates through odata?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: have you tried to get the data after the read has finished?
so, what i mean is let the model load and query the model by oODataModel.create('/PersDataSet', oODataModel.getProperty('/'), ...)

Comment: or let ODataModel use two-way binding and just create a new entity inside this model. hopefully the model will do the rest ;-)

Comment: I think this is already letting the read finish and then trying to create (or I do not understand what you mean :) ). The two-way binding updates automatically in the server?? Did not read this anywhere in the documentation. Many thanks

Comment: whats in your service $metadata, should look something like <Property Name="Endda" Type="Edm.DateTime"/> not Edm.String

Comment: Hi, Yes. DateTime :) 
<EntityType Name="PersData" sap:content-version="1">
<Key>
  <PropertyRef Name="Begda" /> 
  <PropertyRef Name="Endda" /> 
  <PropertyRef Name="Pernr" /> 
</Key>
  <Property Name="Begda" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" Precision="0" sap:label="Date" /> 
  <Property Name="Endda" Type="Edm.DateTime" Nullable="false" Precision="0" sap:label="Date" />
  ...

Comment: try posting in the Gateway Client /IWFND/GW_CLIENT, take the output from a read and post back, that will determine if a UI5 issue

Comment: I did that. The read produces an xml where the attributes do not have m:type="bla". Copying it to a request, it works and I am able to create a new entity. When the same request is generated via ODataModel.create, it generates an xml with incorrect m:type which makes the gateway go boom :) . In fact. a workaround found to this is manually deleting object_to_be_created.__metadata on the javascript side. Still investigating though.. thnaks

Answer (score 2):

the data returned from oODataModel.read is raw, before you post you need to parse it

```
 var handleRead = function (oEvent){
   //Get the data read from backend
   entity = oEvent.results[0];

   var newEntity = jQuery.extend({},entity);
   delete newEntity.__metadata;
   newEntity.Begda = new Date(entity.Begda);
   newEntity.Endda = new Date(entity.Endda);

   //Try to create a new entity with same data
   oODataModel.create('/PersDataSet', newEntity, null, function(){
```

why not use json instead of xml?

Comment: Using json only by itself does not help. It still produces a json request with a messed __metadata attribute. Converting the date strings to Date objects is done so that it works with control bindings. When saving, the opposite is done. Passing a Date to the .create without conversion produces a very different string representation. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the help.
We got this working accounting for the following:

The problem of the wrong types appended to the attributes comes from the read itself. The object returned by read has a __metadata attribute which describes the values. In this object the dates are set with type=edm.string, even when the service says they are DateTime. To me this is a bug of the .read function.

When trying to use the same object to save, create sees the __metatada on the entry and uses those values, producing type edm.string type for the dates. This caused the request to be rejected. Manually changing these __metadata.properties...type to Edm.DateTime makes it work.

In the end, we did the following:

- Dates are parsed manually from the Odata response, creating a js Date
  object from the strings in format "yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00", to make it work with control bindings.  When we want to save, the reverse is done.
- The object to be created is a new object with
  only the attributes we care (no __metadata)