# Adding rows dynamically in a table using ODataModel

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have shown data in the table using **ODataModel** now what I want to achieve is on the click of a button I want to insert new row so that user will be able to enter new data and then on the click of **Save** button all the data/new record will be posted to the server.

I tried searching on this but no luck yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to call .create on the ODataModel and pass it the path and and the entity to create.
After creation you can re-read the data and bind it again.
Check this question for a creation example.

[SAPUI5 Create OData entity with dates - generates incorrect request payload that ends in CX_SXML_PARSE_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768259/sapui5-create-odata-entity-with-dates-generates-incorrect-request-payload-that)

Comment: Thanks jumpifzero, but what if we have the entity created at server end and it's just a matter of adding one new entry in the table? In such case... we have to call createEntry right? Will you please also tell me what do we need to have at server end for this? Help would be appreciated....

Comment: If it is already created in the server then you only need to re-read the table by doing a bindRows again. To create something at the server you need call the .create on the ODataModel. It makes a post request to create an entry.

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida but I think the question was - is it possible to add an empty row to a table so that user can fill it with data and only then create a record on a server? Can you answer this?